# How to make aggregation (summation) of all keys in a dictionary, in case some keys have been repeated more than one time

Tags: python-3.x, csv, dictionary

I am working on csv file.

This is an example of the dictionary:

dictionary = {'1': 3, '7': 1, '642': 1, '2639': 1, '3457': 1, '0': 1}

After I made a filtration of this dataset, I need to make summation for all keys in the dictionary (note that some keys repeated more than once in a dictionary). By using "Output = sum(map(int, dictionary .keys()))" in my code, All keys' values have been aggregated, but I faced a problem that there is repetition of one key which is "1". I really need your help in how to make summation (aggregations) of all keys , in case there is repetition of one or more than one Key in the dictionary.

This is my code:

with open('DataCleaning.csv') as f:

```
data = [{k: str(v) for k, v in row.items()}

    for row in csv.DictReader(f, skipinitialspace=True)]
```

dictionary = {}

for row in data:

```
if 'Saturday' in row["dayofweek_name"] and row ["quarter"] == "1":
    k = row['CASE_COUNT']
    if k in dictionary .keys():
        dictionary [k] += 1
    else:
        dictionary [k] = 1
```

Output = sum(map(int, dictionary .keys()))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use "set" in python like so:

```
sum(map(int, set(dictionary.keys()))
```

set eliminate duplications

for more information go to:
https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/set

Hope that helped

Comment: Thank you so much, Amit. This is in case I want to make summation of all keys, regardless how many times these keys have been repeated. In my case the key "1" has been repeated 3 times and key "0" has been repeated only once. This line code " sum(map(int, set(dictionary.keys()))" will make summation of key  "1" once once and will not make summation of key "0".

Comment: glad I could help :), don't forget to upvote so other people will see this answer too

Comment: Could you please help me in how to make summation of all keys in a dictionary with taking into consideration the repetition of the keys?

Comment: The line you sent it is only make summation of the keys, regardless how many the same key repeats in the dictionary.

Comment: can you rephrase the questions ? if you are trying to sum the keys (not values) then this line should work well. give an example of input and desired output